# Disable ElasticSearch logs in Liferay 7

Tags: elasticsearch, liferay

I've started using Liferay v7, and am getting a lot of the following log messages:

```
17:14:12,265 WARN  [elasticsearch[Mirage][management][T#1]][decider:157] [Mirage] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [fph02E6ISIWnZ5cxWw_mow][Mirage][/Users/randy/FasterPayments/src/eclipse/com.rps.portal/com.rps.portal.backoffice/bundles/data/elasticsearch/indices/LiferayElasticsearchCluster/nodes/0] free: 46gb[9.9%], shards will be relocated away from this node
```

To be honest, I'd rather not spend time learning about ElasticSearch right now, is it possible to simply disable ElasticSearch within Liferay 7 dev environment?  Or other action to remove these log messages?

Comment: Write here pls if you solve the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Control Panel / Configuration / System Settings / Foundation / Elasticsearch.

Under "Additional Configurations" enter

```
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: True
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low: 30gb
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high: 20gb
```

or whatever are appropriate values for your system (there is value in being warned that the disk is *almost* full).

Save & Restart (the values seem not to be picked up at runtime).

[image: Modifying ElasticSearch warning settings]

Answer (score 1):

Liferay needs an index/search engine, say ElasticSearch or SOLR. It defaults to ElasticSearch in DXP. It makes no sense disabling it.
The warnings tell you you've reached your configured disk shared allocation. You can change this settings in your elasticSearch.yml (cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high).
If your logs annoy you, you can change your logging settings. Not sure If it's still valid in DXP, but have a look at https://dev.liferay.com/es/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/6-2/liferays-logging-system.